# Why is my condition failing to hit the if() clause

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI utility to use to update Drupal modules.

I've run into a snag in the process where my script will not hit the `if()` condition:

```
                if(confirm_delete == 'Yes'):
                    print 'Will delete ' + to_delete_modules.split(',')
```

I'm getting output like:
[image: ksskfj]

I'm trying to get it to print the line below, and not hit the `except` statement

```
print 'Will delete ' + to_delete_modules.split(',')
```

Does anyone see anything lingering here?

Comment: your code reaches the if just fine. it's catching an exception in your code inside the if block

Comment: `if` does not need parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects` in your line

```
'Will delete ' + to_delete_modules.split(',')
```

You cannot concatenate 'str' with a 'list' which is returned by `to_delete_modules.split(',')`.
If you print out the exception, you should be able to see that error message:

```
try:
    ...
    print 'Will delete ' + to_delete_modules.split(',') 
except Exception as e: 
    print 'An error occured, please contact author.'
    print e  # TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Comment: @user2107529 Why did you change the question, are you running into another issue?

Comment: Better yet : remove the except clause entirely until you know how to properly handle exceptions...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I agree, the try-except is in OP's origin code and I do it only to suggest him to print the exception then he will see the error.

Comment: @PaulLo My comment was mostly an advice to the OP, sorry I failed to make it clear...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers No mind, and OP updated the question a little bit so his code snippet is not as complete as origin, I hope some of other later viewers don't feel weird.